# Showing Contacts on iOS with Cordova (PhoneGap)

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I am working on a JQuery Mobile app. I want to distribute this app via the AppStore with the help of Cordova (PhoneGap). I want to have a button such that when a user clicks it, their contacts appear. When they choose one, I want to get the email address associated with it if possible. Currently, I have the following:

```
<input id="viewButton" type="button" value="+" onclick="getContact();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  function getContact() {
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    var fields = ["name", "emails"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
  }

  function onContactSuccess() {
    alert("Great");
  }

  function onContactError() {
    alert("oops");
  }
</script>
```

Much to my surprise, I do not see a contact popup. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to change the onSuccess and onError method names. The instance constructor of contacts.find should read:

```
navigator.contacts.find(fields, onContactSuccess, onContactError, options);
```